# Display Hebrew text on Button in Kivy

Tags: kivy

Im trying to get Hebrew text in Kivy Button

i tried downloading a Hebrew supported font from Googlefonts, lets say Arimo
and that how my .kv file looks like

```
<SettingsButton@Button>:
    font_name: 'Arimo_Regular.ttf'

<MainScreen>:
     GridLayout:
         rows: 3
         cols: 1
         SettingsButton:
             text: 'הגדרות'
```

and what im getting is this

[image: Text in Kivy]

any ideas how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Just to inform i solved it by changing font_name for supported language in the relevant class and encoding the .kv file with utf8:
example:

```
    # Building .kv file
    with open('istwithrv.kv', encoding='utf8') as f:
    root_widget = Builder.load_string(f.read())
```